# can rsync show which files are added/updated/deleted?

Tags: rsync

When I run `rsync` with -v it displays all files even if they are not changed.

Is there a mode to show only files that are added/updated/deleted, similar to the output after `git merge`?

Comment: Would that be `--itemize-changes`?

Comment: It shouldn't display files that aren't being updated.  Please use `-i` and include a few lines of the output in your question.  It will provide information on why the file is being selected.  Showing the full command line is a good idea as well.

Comment: Yes `--itemize-changes` `-i` is what I was looking for, although not as easy to read as `git`, that will do!

See here for a schema of rsync's itemize-changes output:

https://caissyroger.com/2020/10/06/rsync-itemize-changes/

Please post it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered. :)